# How to Get the the Current city name using gps in bing map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

I have used bing map in my app,where i locate the current location using gps and i'm getting the co-ordinates using geoco-ordinatewatcher as well and pin the current location with pushpin. but my issue is that i wanna get the current city and country name where the pushpin is pointing. i couldn't get that using map.center property. can anyone help me out.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can use Bing Map Location API as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: no I dont like to use API. is there any default method/service to do that internally in wp7?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get location description (as city, country and so on) without using some kind of web based service.

Answer (score 1):

The following blog post should assist you :-

http://www.nickharris.net/2010/12/how-to-reverse-geocode-a-location-to-an-address-on-windows-phone-7/

Unfortunately, the CivicAddressResolver is currently not implemented on Windows Phone so you would have to use an online based solution.

Answer (score 1):

please, refer the below code

ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();
            // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
            reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeoCodeService.Credentials();
            reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = "Your bing map key";

```
        // Set the point to use to find a matching address
        GeoCodeService.Location point = new GeoCodeService.Location();
        point.Latitude = Your lat;
        point.Longitude = Your lng;

        reverseGeocodeRequest.Location = point;

        // Make the reverse geocode request
        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        geocodeService.ReverseGeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<ReverseGeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodeService_ReverseGeocodeCompleted);
        geocodeService.ReverseGeocodeAsync(reverseGeocodeRequest);
```

void geocodeService_ReverseGeocodeCompleted(object sender, ReverseGeocodeCompletedEventArgse)
        {
                string text1;

```
            GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = e.Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GeoCode Response is :"+geocodeResponse);
            if (geocodeResponse.Results.Count() > 0)
               text1  = geocodeResponse.Results[0].DisplayName;
            else
                text1 = "No Results found";
            textBlock1.Text = text1;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Location is :"+text1);
    }
```

Comment: which namespace/dll to use for the reverse geocode request/respose?

Comment: refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879136.aspx You can include GeocodeService : http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc?wsdl and must change collection type to System.Array (In Configure Service Refrence)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resolve a location from lat/long coordinates on the device.
To do so would require that a database of all places ship with the device to do the lookup. Such a database would be huge and present issues with keeping it updated.